# Error line appears when using drush 7.x.5.9 -- 32-bit executable?

Tags: drush

I keep getting the line "/[~]/drush/drush: line 49: /sw/bin/tput: Bad CPU type in executable" in drush 7.x.5.9 on OS X 10.9.2 Core 2 Duo. I think it's related to a 32-bit executable running on a 64-bit-capable processor. Any ideas? It has only happened since I upgraded to 5.9.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `tput cols` from your shell.  Drush is running this command to determine how many columns wide your terminal is.  You could convince Drush not to call TPUT if you instead `export COLUMNS 80` (e.g. in bashrc), but it's probably better to figure out what's wrong with your tput executable.  This is possibly related to an installation problem that is independent of Drush.